Etymology of Persian زنبور (bee)
In The etymological dictionary of Persian by Mohammad Hassandust, the word زنبور is said to be Iranian in origin and Hassandust references Morgenstierne and also says the Arabic word with the same meaning is borrowed from Iranian. I always assumed an Arabic origin for the word and Wiktionary currently says so and drives it from Proto-Semitic *dVbr- with cognates like Biblical Hebrew דְּבוֹרָה (dəḇorɔ), Classical Syriac ܕܒܘܪܐ (debbōrā), Amharic ዲቧራ (dibʷara) and Aramaic דְּבוֹרְתָא. This root also gives Arabic دبور. So what is the etymology of this word? Is it possible that the word is Iranian and is confused with دبور and is given an Arabic origin?
